# Замаскировать text вводимый в textField!

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Хотелось бы замаскировать text в textField, оставив видимым последний символ (желательно, но не обязательно). Как, я думаю, уже все догадались, для ввода пароля! (^_^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается так:

```
texfield.secureTextEntry = true
```

Или же поставить галочку в `IB` в поле `Secure`

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!!!

Comment: Примите ответ, если он Вам помог.